# Output file not generated by r.viewshed in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, viewshed, qgis-grass-plugin

I'm trying to use `r.viewshed` in PyQGIS to perform Viewshed analysis on a point placed on a raster layer. The algorithm seems to run correctly, as no errors come up, but the output `.tif` file is not created, and I've tried it using multiple different locations, using absolute and relative paths, both with no luck.

Here is a snippet of my python code below.

`rasterLayer` is the `QgsRasterLayer` object, the main raster of the project for the viewshed to be done upon.

```py
pointPath =  r"C:/Users/me/Documents/ZVIs/zvi.tif"
maxRange = 500
pointElevationFromDTM = 100
coordStr = "230049.90500026295, 2841692.311715042"
result = processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed",
                           {'input' : rasterLayer,
                            'coordinates': coordStr,
                            'observer_elevation': pointElevationFromDTM,
                            'max_distance': maxRange,
                            'memory': 300,
                            'output': pointPath})
            
if result['output']:
    print("Viewshed analysis completed. Output saved to:", pointPath)
else:
    print("Viewshed analysis failed")
if os.path.isfile(pointPath):
    print(f"ZVI file was created.")
else:
    print(f"ZVI file was not created")
```

I added in some checks at the end so you can see what I mean. It seems that an output is being created, just not saved for whatever reason.

---

I've been able to print out the processing feedback after the answer by @Taras. The main errors I can see are below:

```
ami_single_temp_name: G_mkstemp() failed: : No such file or directory

Assertion failed: 0, file ami_stream.cpp, line 91 

ERROR: Raster map <outputb422948942aa4ef6a24c5ce880e5fe23> not found

ERROR: Raster map or group <outputb422948942aa4ef6a24c5ce880e5fe23> not found
```

But when using `isValid()` on the raster layer it is returning `True`.

Where do I go next?

I've googled the errors but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: How do I check the log? If you mean the console output, it simply says that the viewshed analysis completed, but the ZVI file was not created. This is just output from the checks at the bottom of my code however.

Comment: I can confirm `coordStr` lies within the `rasterLayer`. The CRS of the `rasterLayer` is EPSG:32615 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 15N. How would I know if the `rasterLayer` CRS matches the `coordStr`? I've just ran it with a maxRange of 10, which should definitely lie within the rasterLayer, and it gave the same issues.

Comment: I don't think I can as it's private data, but I ran the same code on the publicly available raster `SR_50M_alaska_nad.tif` found at `https://download.qgis.org/downloads/data/`, and it is behaving exactly the same, when tested with `coordStr = "1100248.3159823148, 6360501.794258764"`, with `pointElevationFromDTM =100` and `maxRange=10`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are several suggestions regarding your code:

- check firstly alg input and output by means of the [`processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:r.viewshed")`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.viewshed.html)
- as was suggested by @bugmenot123, check the logs. One can access them via putting the [`QgsProcessingFeedback()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeedback.html) class into `processing.run(...)` and after applying the [`textLog()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeedback.html#a6e66e216a3241ff3e60772bc12e41e7d)-method:

  ```py
  feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
  processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed", params, feedback=feedback)
  print(feedback.textLog())
  ```
- use the [Python Try Except blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to handle errors and exceptions, e.g. [`QgsProcessingException`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingException.html).

  ```py
  try:
     params = {
        'input': rlayer,
        'coordinates': coordStr,
        'observer_elevation': pntElevationFromDTM,
        'max_distance': maxRange,
        'output': outputPath
     }
     processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed", params, feedback=feedback)
  except QgsProcessingException as e:
     print(e)
  ```
- apply some useful functions e.g. `basename`, `splitext`, `normpath`, `isfile`, `dirname`, and `join` from the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) library
- use the [`isValid()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ab4d304ac4e8fbd610a00adfa4871845b)-method to check the status of the `QgsRasterLayer`

So, in the end, your code may look like this (*Note:* it was tested within a standalone application):

```py
# imports
from sys import path
from qgis.core import (QgsApplication, QgsRasterLayer, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsProcessingException)
from os.path import (basename, splitext, normpath, isfile, dirname, join)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\plugins', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python\\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()

raster_path = normpath("D:\\qgis_test\\qgis_sample_data\\raster\\SR_50M_alaska_nad.tif")

if isfile(raster_path):

    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster_path, splitext(basename(raster_path))[0])
    coordStr = "3178941, 3504031"
    pntElevationFromDTM = 65  # draped from the raster
    maxRange = 50000
    outputPath = join(dirname(raster_path), "AlaskaViewshed.tif")

    if rlayer.isValid():
        feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

        try:
            params = {
                'input': rlayer,
                'coordinates': coordStr,
                'observer_elevation': pntElevationFromDTM,
                'max_distance': maxRange,
                'output': outputPath
            }
            processing.run("grass7:r.viewshed", params, feedback=feedback)
            print(feedback.textLog())  # read the logs

        except QgsProcessingException as e:
            print(e)
```

With the above code, I could get the output for the [SR_50M_alaska_nad.tif](https://download.qgis.org/downloads/data/) raster on QGIS version 3.28.10-Firenze.

[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [r.series - no output 'ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310626/r-series-no-output-error-6-setcolortable-only-supported-for-byte-or-uint16)
- [QGIS: Getting Concurrent mapset locking error using V.transform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309422/qgis-getting-concurrent-mapset-locking-error-using-v-transform)
- [Returning error text from QgsProcessingFeedback](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382834/returning-error-text-from-qgsprocessingfeedback)

Comment: I thought the issue was fixed but it seems to still be happening. I've printed the feedback to console, and the main errors seem to be:
`ami_single_temp_name: G_mkstemp() failed: : No such file or directory,
Assertion failed: 0, file ami_stream.cpp, line 91,
ERROR: Raster map <outputb422948942aa4ef6a24c5ce880e5fe23> not found,
ERROR: Raster map or group <outputb422948942aa4ef6a24c5ce880e5fe23> not found`

I've tested and the raster returns True from isValid() though. Not sure what the next steps would be

Comment: It seems like my code works some times and other times it does not. Yesterday it was giving those errors, and I haven't changed it, but today it's working fine again. `isfile(raster_path)` returns true at the moment, but I'll let you know what it says if the code stops working again. Really not sure why it's working again today when it wasn't yesterday though.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. Although with the errors above it seemed unable to find the raster? Only way to really know is to wait for it to happen again. I'll let you know if it does.